# VBA - Remove items from combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with an `Unspecified Error` I get while trying to remove duplicated items I have in my combobox...

I first add items using the `RowSource` property.
Then I'd like to delete duplicated values using the `RemoveItem` property.

The error I get is generated at this line : **CompteCOMBO.RemoveItem (j)**

```
        With CompteCOMBO
            .Visible = True
            .RowSource = "Missions!ComptesExistant"
        End With

            For i = 0 To CompteCOMBO.ListCount - 1
               Valeur = CompteCOMBO.List(i)
                For j = i + 1 To CompteCOMBO.ListCount - 1
                    If Valeur = CompteCOMBO.List(j) Then
                        CompteCOMBO.RemoveItem (j) 'ERROR HERE
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
```

Thanks for you help in advance.

Have a good day,

Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few suspect items:

1. Iterating through and deleting at the same time generally needs a lot of care. You can easily end up with errors because you are trying to work with something that has been deleted.
2. Be careful with this line `For j = i + 1 To CompteCOMBO.ListCount - 1`. It will eventually evaluate to something like `For j = 5 to 4`.
3. It shouldn't be causing issues in this case, but don't use brackets here: `CompteCOMBO.RemoveItem (j)`

Instead of removing the duplicates after they are in the combobox, I'd filter out the duplicates first. Use a `Dictionary`, which has a handy `Exists` function.  To use it you need to add a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*. Find it in Tools > References. Something like this would work:

**Module 1**

```
Sub ShowUserform()
    With New UserForm1
        .Show vbModal
    End With
End Sub
```

**UserForm1**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim arr As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary 
    arr = Array("a", "b", "a") 'or similarly:
    'arr = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Missions").Range("CompetesExistant")) 

    For Each v In arr
        If Not d.Exists(v) Then d.Add v, v
    Next v

    Me.ComboBox1.List = d.Keys
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. I don't know much about this scripting dictionnary. This is a company project, I know how to add libraries using code but it's a bit complicated for the problem I am facing (IMO). I just don't get why I cannot delete items from my combobox???

Comment: Hi @Jean-FIC. I would encourage you to get comfortable with dictionaries. They are widely used, and extremely helpful when trying to create unique lists (as you can see above). It's not like you're importing anything new, it's just one of Excel's standard libraries...

Comment: @Jean-FIC, I've added a number of things to watch out for. But I don't intend to test the code specifically. I would strongly recommend attacking it from another angle, as mentioned above.

Comment: I've see your updates, thank you. I'm trying with your method because even using simply "RemoveItem" without checking if it is a duplication, it won't work. Will keep in touch when I'm done.

Comment: I'm trying to add my named range like you said : arr = Application.Transpose("Missions!ComptesExistant") but it doesn't work. Thought when I put "A1:A5" it does work. I get an error 13 "invalid or unsupported executable format"... :S

Comment: It does work with that : arr = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Missions").Range("ComptesExistant"))

Comment: @Jean-FIC, sorry, I got the format wrong there -- updated

Comment: Yup, figured it out :) Thanks for your time!